# Register symbol and parenthesis causing error in outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

when using a sender profile with "xyz® (abc) communications" for the from name, the part in parenthesis is being kicked out when sent to outlook so i just have "xyz® communications"

I have tried dynamically pulling it in from a data extension as well as using the html code for the symbol but still nothing. I know its a problem with the registered symbol in outlook because when i take it out "(abc)" appears again.

Any help would be great. again this is only in outlook

Comment: it works on Gmail and any other email provider?

Comment: yes, the full from name is showing up with all other providers "xyz® (abc) communications".

Comment: It looks more like outlook issue and not something related to marketing cloud